# how to use asyncTask + location listener if the listener is in a different class than my Activity?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I want to give the user some offers based on his current location.

Which means the ui should wait (not be blocked, but wait with animation)- so i have thought to use location listener and an asyncTask.

but the listener signature returns void

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
```

and an asynTask won't help here (as it's a saperated class from my activity)

how would you suggest doing this?

Comment: Just implement your own callback/interface (eg. onLocationFound(double lat, double lng)and fire this event in your Activity? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: but then i can i access it from the locationManager class? and how can the ui thread wait to it?

Comment: Just give me 5min I will write u an example

Comment: have u seen my suggestion and do u understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
public class MyLocationListener extends LocationListener{

    public interface MyLocCallbacks{
        onLocFound(double lat, double lng);
    }

    private MyLocCallbacks mCallbacks;

    public MyLocationListener(MyLocCallbacks callback){
        this.mCallbacks = callback;

        //Make sure to start the LocationSerivce here
    }   

    public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
        this.mCallbacks.onLocFound(log.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()) 
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity implements MyLocCallbacks{

    private MyLocationListener mLocListener;

    onCreate(S...){
        mLocListener = new MyLocationListener(this);  //this for the interface
    }

    //This one is called by your Location Listener
    @Override
    onLocFound(double lat, double lng){
        startAnimation();
    }


    private void startAnimation(){
        //do here your startAnimation, 
        //before you could show a simple loading screen
    }
}
```

Comment: i meant i want to run animation as progress bar, during the waiting time. not when recieved

Comment: yeah so start it in your oncreate and stop it in the startAnimation()